# highlight matched word with or without special marks

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to implement this code for my search function which will highlight matched keywords in the result. It is working great but the problem is it won't highlight keywords with special marks like:

$text="iphone mới";

Question 1: If keyword is "mới" it will highlight the word "mới" in $text. But if keyword is "moi", it won't highlight it. By the way, mới = new in my language. So how can i adjust this code to make it work?

Question 2: Also how to make it highlight part of word in $text like: If keyword is "iph" it will also highlight iph of the word iphone in $text.

Many thanks in advance...!!!

```
<?php
function highlightWords($text, $words)
{
    /*** loop of the array of words ***/
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
            /*** quote the text for regex ***/
            $word = preg_quote($word);
            /*** highlight the words ***/
            $text = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i", '<span class="highlight_word">\1</span>', $text);
    }
    /*** return the text ***/
    return $text;
}


/*** example usage ***/
$text = 'This text will highlight PHP and SQL and sql but not PHPRO or MySQL or sqlite';
/*** an array of words to highlight ***/
$words = array('php', 'sql');
/*** highlight the words ***/
$highlighttext =  highlightWords($string, $words);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHPRO Highlight Search Words</title>
<style type="text/css">
.highlight_word{
    background-color: pink;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $string; ?>
```

Comment: 1.) `o` != `ớ` pattern would have to be something like `m[oớ]i` and use with `u` flag (if pattern & input is utf-8) 2.) You've set `\b` word boundaries, remove them, eg `$text = preg_replace("/$word/i", '<span class="highlight_word">\0</span>', $text);`

Comment: Thank for answering my question 2, it is working now, awsome. ABout question 1, could you please explain it abit further, sorry I am just a new learner... thank you

Comment: @GiangNguyen Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), it highlights matches inside the DOM and has an option for diacritic characters! If you would like to map highlight characters that aren't diacritics, you can add your custom synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
function highlightWords($str, $replaceWord)
{
    $new = '<span class="highlight_word">'.$replaceWord.'</span>';

    $str = preg_replace_callback( "/$replaceWord/", function( $match) use( $new) {
        return $new;
    }, $str);

    return $str;
}
```